# Some badge pages truncate users' badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css, badges

[Certain badge pages](https://dba.stackexchange.com/badges/63/convention) only allow a maximum width for a username + badges, and since we have [some users who choose to use ridiculously long and impossible to spell usernames](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2092/concernedoftunbridgewells), this causes truncation of badge counts:

> [image]

This seems to be unique to the dba.SE CSS, as [the main site's equivalent page does not show this truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/901/convention).

Still seems to truncate things weirdly, e.g. on [this page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/badges/63/convention) Concerned's name is truncated (there is more than one well in Tunbridge) and the `to` seems to unnecessarily word wrap (there is a ton of white space available to the right):

> [image]

Comment: Seems to me the only real answer is to downvote all the answers from those posters to prevent truncation.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129269/badge-holders-page-broken

Comment: Thanks @Jon, I hadn't seen that one, and a spot check of a few badge pages on SO (including [Convention](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/901/convention)) did not reveal similar behavior. I see ample spacing between the columns, but perhaps that has to do with filling a page (which the above tag doesn't do yet).

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed by badges changes of some months ago:

[image]

Comment: Please see my update, still some weird truncation on some pages.

Comment: User info cards have a fixed width and are truncated by design. I don't think we will fix this.